# jfxrt.jar missing on Linux in Java 1.8.0_77

Tags: linux, javafx

I have _Oracle 1.8.0_77_ installed on my *Linux* workstation and `jfxrt.jar` is missing. And I have already looked in `jre/lib` and `jre/lib/ext`. Do I have to now install the *JavaFX SDK* in order to get this capability? Or other ideas?

Answer (score 3):

That's weird, you may have a corrupted installation or have not installed the Java version you thought you did.

1. Go to Oracle's J[Java SE Development Kit 8 Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) page.
2. Download the latest linux version from there (currently it is `jdk-8u91-linux-x64.tar.gz`).
3. When you extract the tar file you downloaded, you will find `jfxrt.jar` in the `jre/lib/ext` directory.

Comment: Figured it out. This is a continuous build environment where I always used a server deployed version. The server JRE in 1.7 included the jfxrt.jar file. The server JRE for 1.8 does not. Downloaded the JDK and it's all there. I'll just use the JDK version in the future. Thanks!